# 304 response from a non modifying POST request

Tags: rest, post, http-status-code-304, http-status-code-412

I am working on a POST HTTP API which does not modify or create any state on the server. The API is implemented with method POST as it needs to accept multiple complex inputs which would not be possible using query parameters.

What is the correct response status to return in case of conditional check failures (`If-Match`/`If-None-Match`) for such read-only POST APIs, should it be `304 Not Modified` or `412 Precondition Failed`?

Note: This is an internal service API where the client is aware that it is a non modifying request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a GET request, we would expect an If-None-Match header, which would normally produce a 200 response with an updated copy of the representation if the condition holds, and a 304 response when the precondition fails (meaning that the clients copy of the resource is already up to date).

The semantics should be the same when we use POST in a read-only way.  (Note that we are in a bit of an edge case here; a general purpose client won't normally know that this *particular* POST request is safe, and probably won't know which precondition headers to attach to the request.  For instance, if you try to use an HTML form in a web browser to access this resource, you probably aren't going to get the conditional headers that you want.)

412 Precondition Failed is normally used when requesting a modification to the resource, in combination with an If-Match header.

Reference: [HTTP Semantics, section 13](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-semantics#section-13).